# SQL: Ignore some returned rows, deleting others

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I have this table :

```
| Column        | Type                           |
+---------------+--------------------------------+         
| id            | integer                        |
| recipient_id  | integer                        | 
| is_read       | boolean                        | 
| updated_at    | timestamp(0) without time zone |
```

I have to delete items from this table with this specific rule:

- for each `recipient_id`, we keep the 5 last read items, and we delete the old read one.

I tried to bend my mind with `RECURSIVE WITH` statements but failed miserably. I've implemented my solution programmatically but I wanted to know if there was a decent pure SQL solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM tbl t
USING (
    SELECT id, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY recipient_id
                                  ORDER BY updated_at DESC) as rn
    FROM   tbl
    WHERE  is_read
  ) x
WHERE  x.rn > 5
AND    x.id = t.id;
```

A `JOIN` is usually faster than an IN expression, especially with larger numbers of items.
And use [`row_number()`, not `rank()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html#FUNCTIONS-WINDOW-TABLE)!

Answer (score 0):

```
delete from t
where id in (
    select id
    from (
        select 
            id, 
            row_number() over(partition by recipient_id order by updated_at desc) rn
        from t
        where is_read
    ) s
    where s.rn > 5
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/tutorial-window.html):

```
DELETE FROM table
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT id
  FROM (
    SELECT id, rank() OVER (PARTITION BY recipient_id ORDER BY updated_at DESC) as position
    FROM table
    WHERE is_read
  ) subselect WHERE position > 5
)
```